# How to append to a list but skip a line?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to store values of length 150 into a list array but I want to skip a line each iteration. This is what I have which doesnt function. freq_data_1 has size (150,) which I try to append to freq_data which occurs but when I try to skip to the next line, it wont work. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import pi 
from scipy.fftpack import fft

freq_data = []
freq_data_2 = []

for i in range(len(video_samples)):
    
     freq_data_1 = fft(video_samples[i,:])
     freq_data.append(freq_data_1[i])
     freq_data_2 = '\n'.join(freq_data)
```

My video_samples is an array of (4000,150) meaning I have 4000 signals of length in time of 150 steps. I want my output to be the same size as this but storing the frequency output.

Video_samples is a collection of signals with slightly varying frequency for each signal/row. e.g.

```
Input:
[0.775 0.3223 0.4613 0.2619 0.4012 0.567
 0.908 0.4223 0.5128 0.489 0.318  0.187]
```

The first row is one of my signals of length 6. The second row is another signal of length 6. Each of these signals represent a frequency with added noise.

I wish to take each row separately, use the FFT on it to obtain the frequency of that signal and then store it in a matrix where each row would represent the FFT of that signal.

Comment: have a variable "count" that you increment by 1 in your for loop. Make the appending conditional upon the count not equalling a certain value.

Comment: What is the expected output ? I don't understand your question

Comment: what type is video_samples?  [i,:] should be [1:], right?  what is fft? --include import numpy... (fast fourier(sp?) xform?)

Comment: I edited my post, hopefully that makes more sense? @Ram

Comment: No, it still doesn't make enough sense. Just show a sample of your data (not necessary to write down all the 4000x150 elements, it can be just a few ones, 3x4 for exampe): what do you have, and what do you expected to get.

Comment: What is your actual input? Is it text?  Is it data read from a sensor?  If it's text, is it formatted?  Comma separated with some separator (perhaps a newline) between signals?  Json?  Some other format?

Comment: it is an array of float32, as shown in the output example I gave @WilliamPursell

Comment: @HarrietTreacy The output example you give does not say anything about the input.  Also, the output example you give is not an array of float 32, it is text.  Is your input really a python object?  Is it a flat list, or is it a list of tuples, or a list of lists?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Apologies, I meant that the output of the video_samples is that array I gave. The video_samples is type numpy.ndarray, I don't know if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip a line"?  An array does not have any sort of concept of "line".

Answer (score 0):

Another guess...

```
import numpy as np   # it's not necessary for this snippet actually

def fft(lst): return [x*2 for x in lst] # just for example

# 2d array, just a guess
video_samples = [
    [0.775, 0.3223, 0.4613, 0.2619, 0.4012, 0.567], 
    [0.908, 0.4223, 0.5128, 0.489, 0.318, 0.187],
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
    [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
]

video_samples = np.array(video_samples, dtype = 'float')  # 2d list to ndarray just for example
print('video samples (input?): \n', video_samples)

matrix1 = []
matrix2 = []

for s1, s2 in zip(video_samples[::2], video_samples[1::2]):
    matrix1.append(fft(s1))
    matrix2.append(fft(s2))

matrix1 = np.array(matrix1, dtype = 'float')  # just for example
matrix2 = np.array(matrix2, dtype = 'float')  # just for example
print('\nmatrix1:\n', matrix1)
print('\nmatrix2:\n', matrix2)
```

Output:

```
video samples (input?): 
 [[0.775  0.3223 0.4613 0.2619 0.4012 0.567 ]
 [0.908  0.4223 0.5128 0.489  0.318  0.187 ]
 [0.1    0.2    0.3    0.4    0.5    0.6   ]
 [0.7    0.8    0.9    0.1    0.2    0.3   ]]

matrix1:
 [[1.55   0.6446 0.9226 0.5238 0.8024 1.134 ]
 [0.2    0.4    0.6    0.8    1.     1.2   ]]

matrix2:
 [[1.816  0.8446 1.0256 0.978  0.636  0.374 ]
 [1.4    1.6    1.8    0.2    0.4    0.6   ]]
```

Five guys for two (or more?) days can't get what do you mean. Amazing.